# What does this ajax code do?

Tags: javascript, ajax

So i'm a little stuck
can someone please look at this function in my work:

```
function showUser(str) {
    if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","venue2.php?hotel="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Can someone explain what this function actually does please?
also can i adapt it to make it work in a form?

Comment: apparently it is an AJAX GET call in old style. Where did you stuck?

Comment: Thats an oldschool AJAX call. Times without jQuery were hard obv ...

Answer (score 3):

```
function showUser(str) {
    //in this part if str is null then clear the element "txtHint":
    //============================================================
    if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
     } 

     //In this part create an object xmlhttp responsible on transactions :
     //==================================================================
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else { // code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }

     //define the function "onreadystatechange", will be called when receving data:
     //===========================================================================
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
         // verify the state of data received , if we receive all data and all is OK
         //=========================================================================
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
             //trans the data received to txtHint:
             document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
     }

  //now, we call the the Url with the param hotel in GET:
  //====================================================
  xmlhttp.open("GET","venue2.php?hotel="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function is an AJAX(=Asynchron Javascript and XML) Request without using any popular framework like dojo or jquery. AJAX is used to create requests without reloading the page. For example: 
When you open stackoverflow, you are getting logged in automatically after some seconds without having to reload the page.
Basically it checks if the given parameter `str` is empty. If yes, clear the element's value with the id 'txtHint'. If its not empty, its getting the value of the element 'txtHint' and puts it into the request. Then it adds `'hotel=str'.`

Answer (score 0):

It makes an Ajax call to file venue2.php passing the parameter hotel width value  equals to str.
  If the call is ok, it will put the response Text inside the html tag with the id = txtHint

Comment: is it possible to do this using a form?

Comment: It is a function. You can call it passing it your string in onsubmit event of your form ,click event on a button or blur event of  the textbox where you are inputting the hotel name string

Answer (score 0):

1) Function gets one argument called `str`.

2) It checks if `str` is empty string. And if that empty then break the code execution (return).

3) If `str` is not empty, then create `XMLHttpRequest object` and send request to `venue2.php` with parameter hotel=str from arguments.

4) And when request is done then load response into `txtHint` div.